# Android - Default Activity Cannot Be Found

Tags: java, android, xml, launcher

I am making a basic custom launcher by following the given instructions on a site... The instructions say that the app can be launched, but when I try, I get an error saying the default activity not found.

I looked into the existing questions on stack overflow but none of them helped me. My manifest is this...

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="omg_its_azzler.launcher">

  <activty>
    <application android:allowBackup="true"
        android:name="omg_its_azzler.launcher.HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"/>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
  </activty>

  <activity>
    android:name="omg_its_azzler.launcher.AppsActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
  </activity>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please check the spelling of activity. It seems you have spelt it wrong twice. Maybe the error is due to that.

Comment: Thanks... but still not working... same error...

Comment: Please, paste the manifest correctly. You have put a tag application inside a tag activity... it is the first time I see something like that.

Comment: Place the activity tags within the application tags.

Answer (score 1):

You got the syntax of the manifest wrong. The application tag is the tag you keep all the activities inside of.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

package="omg_its_azzler.launcher">
    <application android:allowBackup="true"
        android:name="omg_its_azzler.launcher.HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"/>


    <activity>
        android:name="omg_its_azzler.launcher.AppsActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

The application tag is the root tag for all activities, and the intent filter goes inside the activity tag

Comment: How can be the ending tag </application> when you have already closed it earlier??

Answer (score 0):

All `<activity>...</activity>` should be in `<application>...</application>`.

In your manifest your `<activity>` tag is outside the `<application>...</application>` and closing tag `</activity>` is inside it.

This is the `AndroidManifest.xml` structure:

```
<uses-permission />
<permission />
<permission-tree />
<permission-group />
<instrumentation />
<uses-sdk />
<uses-configuration />  
<uses-feature />  
<supports-screens />  
<compatible-screens />  
<supports-gl-texture />  

<application>

    <activity>
        <intent-filter>
            <action />
            <category />
            <data />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data />
    </activity>

    <activity-alias>
        <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
        <meta-data />
    </activity-alias>

    <service>
        <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
        <meta-data/>
    </service>

    <receiver>
        <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
        <meta-data />
    </receiver>

    <provider>
        <grant-uri-permission />
        <meta-data />
        <path-permission />
    </provider>

    <uses-library />

</application>
```